# Order of srv records in Active Directory DNS

Tags: dns, active-directory

I'm trying to learn DNS srv records behaviour inside Windows Server DNS currently and struggling to understand a couple of things:

1. I set up two RWDC and one RODC in a single site. It was default "add roles-next-next-next" installation. Each DC has DNS.

When I open records on RWDC1 inside _tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.domainname I see this list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXqZZ.png
Notice the _kerberos records order - s-dc01, s-rodc, s-dc00
Notice the _ldap recors order      - s-dc00, s-dc01, s-rodc

When I open records on RWDC2 inside _tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.domainname I see this list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7PMx.png
Notice the _kerberos records order - s-rodc, s-dc00, s-dc01
Notice the _ldap recors order      - s-dc00, s-dc01, s-rodc

When I open records on RODC inside _tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.domainname I see this list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuVFA.png
Notice the _kerberos records order - s-dc00, s-dc01, s-rodc
Notice the _ldap recors order      - s-rodc, s-dc00, s-dc01

Also notice that each record has the same priority and weight.

So my question is - Why records is in different order on each DNS server, what is the cause and does it matter in a process of client chosing DC while quering DNS records?

2. If all records have the same priority and weight - how client choses which DC to use?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the different DNS has different order of the records, I think it could be related to when the DNS replicate the DNS records from other DNS.

And according to my understanding, the order of DNS records does not seem to have any effect. So it should not matter that the client how to choose.

Finally, the client should firstly choose the DNS in the TCP/IP setting, we can see by `ipconfig /all` in cmd.exe. Then the DNS will random select one of records to rely to the clients.(If they have the same priority and weight).